# Como acceder a valores de una lista de un diccionario de forma dinámica en Python

Tags: python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una diccionario como este el cual tiene listas anidadas:

```
data =
{
    "id": 212,
    "primer_apellido": "Apellido1",
    "segundo_apellido": "Apellido2",
    "primer_nombre": "Nombre1",
    "segundo_nombre": "Nombre2",
    "genero": "masculino",
    "lugar_de_nacimiento": "Lugar Nacimiento",
    "facultad": "",
    "departamento": "",
    "categoria": "P2",
    "apellido": "Apellido1 Apellido2",
    "nombre": "Nmbre1 Nombre2",
    "related": {
        "articulos": [
            {
                "id": 2557
            },
            {
                "id": 2256
            },
            {
                "id": 2312
            }
        ],
        "libros": [
            {
                "id": 535
            },
            {
                "id": 537
            },
            {
                "id": 538
            }
        ],
        "proyectos": [],
        "grado-academico": [],
        "capacitacion": []
    }
}
```

Ingreso al elemento `related` y saco `articulos` de la siguiente forma:

```
listaidArticulos = []
for i in data['related']['articulos']:
  listaidArticulos.append(i)

print('lista-->>>>>>>>>',listaidArticulos)
```

Lo cual me devuelve:

```
lista-->>>>>>>>> [{'id': 2557}, {'id': 2256}, {'id': 2312}]
```

Mi pregunta es, como puedo acceder a *articulos, libros, proyectos, grado-academico, capacitacion* y obtener los valores de forma dinámica, es decir que no tenga que poner `for i in data['related']['articulos']:` o `for i in data['related']['libros']` indicando a cual quiero acceder. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay alguna cosa que no entiendo muy bien en tu código...

¿Para qué haces lo siguiente?:

```
listaidArticulos = []
for i in data['related']['articulos']:
  listaidArticulos.append(i)

print('lista-->>>>>>>>>', listaidArticulos)
```

Que te devuelve `lista-->>>>>>>>> [{'id': 2557}, {'id': 2256}, {'id': 2312}]`

Si directamente con `print('lista-->>>>>>>>>', data['related']['articulos'])` te va a devolver lo mismo. Es decir, `data['related']['articulos']` ya es una lista que tiene lo mismo que estás metiendo en `listaidArticulos`.

En principio no parece que necesites volver a almacenar los datos en listas nuevas puesto que los tienes almacenados ya en `data` (¿Para qué duplicarlos?), sino que más bien necesitas saber cómo acceder a estos. Aún así si necesitas almacenarlos en una lista nueva por alguna razón, ponlo en los comentarios. Digo esto porque en tu pregunta hablas de 'acceder a los datos'.

Independientemente de esto, puedes obtener lo que hay dentro de `related` iterando por sus elementos:

```
for f in data['related']:
    print(f'{f}-->>>>>>>>> {data["related"][f]}')
```

En este caso, `f` iría tomando como valor las claves de los diccionarios, y `data["related"][f]` su valor, y esto te devolvería:

```
articulos-->>>>>>>>> [{'id': 2557}, {'id': 2256}, {'id': 2312}]
libros-->>>>>>>>> [{'id': 535}, {'id': 537}, {'id': 538}]
proyectos-->>>>>>>>> []
grado-academico-->>>>>>>>> []
capacitacion-->>>>>>>>> []
```

Si lo que quieres es una lista con los `id's`, que en este caso sería lo más lógico, puedes hacerlo así:

```
for f in data['related']:
    lista = [items['id'] for items in data['related'][f]]
    print(f'{f}-->>>>>>>>> {lista}')
```

Que te devolvería lo siguiente:

```
articulos-->>>>>>>>> [2557, 2256, 2312]
libros-->>>>>>>>> [535, 537, 538]
proyectos-->>>>>>>>> []
grado-academico-->>>>>>>>> []
capacitacion-->>>>>>>>> []
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a ser directos :/, la forma en la que te voy a presentar la solución es una función recursiva, la recursividad no es buena debido a que las llamadas se van acumulando, si son muchas terminas teniendo un *stackoverflow*, solo procura no utilizarlo con datos muy grandes.

En esta función vamos a iterar en los valores del diccionario, si su valor es otro diccionario, pues hacemos una llamada a la misma función, si es una lista, iteramos en sus elementos (que serán diccionarios) y llamamos a la misma función, en caso contrario significa que el valor es un *string* o un *integer*, por lo que solamente guardamos el valor en una lista llamada `elementos`

```py
def sacar(data,elementos = None):
    if elementos == None: elementos = []
    #iteramos el diccionario
    for v in data.values():
        #si el valor es diccionario lo pasamos otra vez
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            sacar(v,elementos)
        #si el valor es una lista itermos en sus valores
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            #sacamos sus valores
            for e in v:
                sacar(e,elementos) 
        else:
            elementos.append(v)
    return elementos
```

**Probamos**

```
print(sacar(data))
```

**Resultado**

```py
[212,
 'Apellido1',
 'Apellido2',
 'Nombre1',
 'Nombre2',
 'masculino',
 'Lugar Nacimiento',
 '',
 '',
 'P2',
 'Apellido1 Apellido2',
 'Nmbre1 Nombre2',
 2557,
 2256,
 2312,
 535,
 537,
 538]
```

Si lo quieres hacer sin recursividad creo que tendrás que usar algún modulo como *integemeter* o algo parecido.

Comment: Solo podrás tener un stack overflow en python si tu se lo permites cambiando la cantidad de recursiones permitidas, normalmente el programa simplemente tirara error al llegar al limite como medida de "seguridad"

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo que lo que quieres es conseguir los valores `"id"` que se encuentran en los elementos dentro del diccionario `"related": {...}` y guardarlos en una lista, podrías hacer lo siguiente(al final hay otra forma de iterar como esta pero considero esta mas confiable):

```
listaId = []

for dic in data['related'].values(): 
    for e in dic:
        listaId+=[e['id']]

print(listaId)
```

Con Resultado:

```
[2557, 2256, 2312, 535, 537, 538]
```

Pero si lo que buscas es un formato de `[{id:algo1},{id:algo2},{id:algo3},...]` (que no veo sentido de repetir `"id"`, a menos que esperas que haya otro elemento aparte de `"id"`):

```
listaId = []
    
for dic in data['related'].values():
    listaId+=dic
    
print(listaId)
```

Con resultado:

```
[{'id': 2557}, {'id': 2256}, {'id': 2312}, {'id': 535}, {'id': 537}, {'id': 538}]
```

**Nota final:** En mi experiencia no es bueno tener mucho "dinamismo" como quieres con los diccionarios porque se suponen que contienen información identificable que fue almacenada para ser recuperada, no simplemente datos random que almacenas en estas (a menos que esto sea lo que busques), todos estos métodos dependen del hecho de que la estructura dentro `"related"` no sea modificada de forma abrupta, si esto llega a pasar es mejor crear métodos distintos para cada cosa que quieras sacar aunque pueda parecer tedioso.

**EDIT:** Después de probar las formas de iterar cambie el anterior código de la primera forma porque es mas directo con lo que busca(es decir `"id"`), a continuación dejo el viejo código que había dejado(que igualmente funciona):

```
listaId = []
    
for dic in data['related'].items():
    listaId+=dic[1]
    
print(listaId)
```